# Date format angular $resource

Tags: angularjs, http, date, resources

I'm creating a date on an object and storing it in indexeddb but when sending the object with the date fields I'm losing the daylight saving hour and getting the date with incorrect time.

I'm creating the date using

```
moment().toDate()
```

which gives me currently

```
Fri Jun 12 2015 15:23:40 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

but when retrieving the date I get back the date without the DST hour added on. It seems to be something from once I call a PUT request through angulars $resource.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: Not sure but it might be something to do with how angular calls stringify on the object. I put my object in the console.info and its fine as the original object but then I did

    JSON.stringify(myObject)

and viewed in the console, it has ignore DST and im missing the hour